# android.widget.imageview cannot be cast to android.view.viewgroup (only in android, ios is OK)

Tags: android, debugging, react-native, nested, imageview

I developed a project in react native 0.43.3

I made a mistake developing and testing all project only in iOS. (Works fine there)

The problem was when I tried to generate the APK to upload to PlayStore, and testing in a device I found the error:

android.widget.imageview cannot be cast to android.view.viewgroup

My main problem is about how the error is displayed. Is in the red screen of dead, and I have no idea how to find the line and component in react native where is the error happening. I think maybe I cannot realized that because the javascript code is already compiled.

Anyway, I don't know how to solve the problem.

I think maybe is because I using spinners inside of images (to show the image is being loaded), something like:

```
  <View style={[styles.resourceActions]}>
      <Image
        style={{width: imgWidth, height: imgHeight}}
        source={{uri: this.props.imageUrl}}
        onLoad = {() => this.setState({ loading: false })}
      >
      <ActivityIndicator
          animating={this.state.loading}
          style={[styles.spinner, styles.centering, {marginTop: this.state.loadingMarginTop}]}
          size="large"
        />
        </Image>
    </View>
```

But I have no idea because I use imageview (and fastimage component) in a lot of parts and views

my dependencies:

```
"@remobile/react-native-refresh-infinite-listview": "^1.0.6",
"react": "16.0.0-alpha.6",
"react-native": "0.43.3",
"react-native-camera": "git+https://github.com/lwansbrough/react-native-camera.git",
"react-native-device-info": "^0.10.2",
"react-native-fast-image": "0.0.9",
"react-native-google-analytics-bridge": "^5.0.1",
"react-native-htmlview": "^0.9.0",
"react-native-loading-spinner-overlay": "^0.4.4",
"react-native-material-design": "^0.3.7",
"react-native-modalbox": "^1.3.9",
"react-native-photo-view": "^1.2.0",
"react-native-qrcode-scanner": "0.0.11",
"react-native-qrcode-svg": "^5.0.0",
"react-native-radio-buttons": "^0.14.0",
"react-native-router-flux": "3.38.0",
"react-native-share": "^1.0.20",
"react-native-side-menu": "^0.20.1",
"react-native-svg": "^5.1.7",
"react-native-vector-icons": "^4.0.1"
```

thanks for any orientation in my problem

Answer (score 1):

**Casting** (in this case downcasting)

To make it simple is taking an Object of one particular type and “turning it into” another Object type which inherits from the first.
Casting is not check at compile time but at runtime.
Basically you are saying to the compiler '*Trust me, you can treat this object as if it were of this type*'.

Example:

```
Object aSentenceObject = "This is just a regular sentence";
String aSentenceString = (String) aSentenceObject;
```

Now.. remember when I say I it is checked at runtime? So what happen if casting cannot be done?
Let's say in this case:

```
Object aSentenceObject = "This is just a regular sentence";
int aSentenceString = (int) aSentenceObject;
```

Since aSentenceObject cannot be casted to int an exception will be thrown. Something like this

```
ClassCastException: java.lang.Object cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer
```

**But what does this have to do with your case?**

> "With React Native, you don't build a “mobile web app”, an “HTML5 app”,
>   or a “hybrid app”. You build a real mobile app that's
>   indistinguishable from an app built using Objective-C or Java. React
>   Native uses the same fundamental UI building blocks as regular iOS and
>   Android apps."

As it is said in the official React Native page at some point your JavaScript code somehow compiles to native language(in android case, Java).

> We can see that [each React Native control will interact with a native
>   counterpart component](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p1SGM.png).
>   "We are ‘allowed’ to write JavaScript because React Native presents us
>   with a control which is written in JavaScript. But this is always
>   underpinned by the phones actual native counterpart. React Native
>   simply allows the bridge for the two way communication to happen"
>   As it is explained in [this article](https://www.logicroom.co/react-native-architecture-explained/)

**In native android, Images cannot have children (like ScrollView or ViewGroup do)**
So in this process of translating your JS code to Java the "translating machine" try to treat your Image as a ViewGroup, cos it has children.
The result is what you get

```
android.widget.imageview cannot be cast to android.view.viewgroup
```

**Conclusion**

If you remove that nested structure and place the ActivityIndicator component as a sibling of the Image component it should be fixed

Answer (score 0):

In **Native Android** also, we cannot cast an `ImageView` to `ViewGroup` as the `ImageView` does not extend the class `ViewGroup`. Actually, this casting is not possible.

Comment: what "cast" does mean in this context? is when I do `<View><Image /></View>` ? or when I do `<Image><ActivityIndicator /></Image>` ? How I should solve the problem? Sorry for so many question in same sentence, but is because I want to understand all thinks that I don't know, many thanks